# Out-String a result of a CMDLET and manipulate it in PowerShell

Tags: string, powershell, split

I have a variable that gives me the canocical name of an object in Active Directory:

```
$LastOU = Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Filter * -Properties * |
          Sort { $_.WhenCreated } -Descending |
          Select -First 1 {$_.CanonicalName} |
          Out-String
```

If I run the command as `Write-Host $LastOU`it indeeds gives me the result I expected:

> @{$_.CanonicalName=domain.local/Microsoft/Userz}

What I'm trying to do now is to manipulate the string to only have

> Microsoft

selected.

I used the `Out-String` method to have the result of the command as a string.

After, what I do is use the `.Split()`-function to manipulate my result.

I do this like `$CompName = $LastOU.Split(...)`.

However I get the error:

> Method invocation failed because [Selected.Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADOrganizationalUnit] does not contain a method named 'Split'.

This means that my result is not a string? But what is wrong in my command?

Comment: `Select -First 1 {$_.CanonicalName} | Out-String` -> `Select -First 1 -Expand CanonicalName`

Comment: `Get-Member -InputObject $LastOU` will tell you the type of the variable and the methods and members available. Also, where something has an 'automatic' string representation, you can probably use the `-split` operator to manipulate it, instead of trying to use a possibly-nonexistent `.split()` method.

Comment: Thank you very much for the comments,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your select statement to include -ExpandProperty, which should just give you the string back instead of an object.

Change this

```
Select -First 1 {$_.CanonicalName} |Out-String
```

to this

```
Select -ExpandProperty CanonicalName -first 1
```